# VB.Net GeckoFX disable dialog errors

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

While the title might be confusing, I hope this will explain it better.
So, I want to make an VB.Net webbrowser with a GeckoWebBrowser control.
The issue I am facing is that Gecko keeps opening error dialogs even tho I am catching the Error in my code. I just want to disable those dialogs and load an simple html site instead.

Code (Where wbMain is the GeckoWebBrowser control):

```
Function navigate(ByVal address As String)
    Try
        wbMain.Navigate(address)
    Catch ex As Exception
        wbMain.LoadHtml("<h1>An error has occurred!</h1><p>Description: " & ex.Message & "</p>")
    End Try
End Function
```

Gecko keeps doing those errors:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxdJH.png) (I can't post images yet)

But I just want it to display the html page instead of the dialog.

I apologize if I wasn't clear enough or have broken english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose these are the browser alerts, so you need to create your own service which catches these messages.

Create a class which implements the `nsIPromptService2` and `nsIPrompt` prompt interface. In VB syntax is like that I suppose:

```
class FilteredPromptService Implements nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt
```

And then override all the methods required by these interfaces with your own custom logic.